# Getting an Out of Memory exception even after allocating memory. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

There are 55 images in the folder, none of them are bigger than 80kb, the biggest is 78kb, while most of the others are between 30-50kb
I have this block of code that makes a picturebox for each picture found in a folder then it adds them all to a flowlayoutpanel

It shows an Out of Memory exception at `PictureBox picture = new()`
I have tried  changing the platform target to x64 in the build options, adding an App.config and adding this to it `<gcallowverylargeobjects enabled="true"></gcallowverylargeobjects>` and finally I added a `GC.Collect()` but none of these helped. It still throws the exception

If I move the pictures out of the folder, then slowly add them instead of adding them to the folder all at once, it works and the error doesn't appear. All my images are PNG.
Also I think it's worth noting that it doesn't appear at all if there only 4 images, once I start adding more the error occurs more often

[image: Call stack trace.]

**My code:**

```
 for (int pictureCreator = 0; pictureCreator < files.Length; pictureCreator++)
            {
                FileInfo file = files[pictureCreator];
                if (file.FullName.EndsWith(FileFormats[3]))
                {
                    string url = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                    if (url != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            GC.Collect();
                            Image gif = Image.FromStream(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url));
                            PictureBox picture = new()
                            {
                                Name = url,
                                Size = new(45, 45),
                                Image = gif,
                                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                            };
                            picture.Click += Gif_Click;
                            flowLayoutPanelGif.Controls.Add(picture);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
```

**The block of code where the issue is caused:**

```
 if (file.FullName.EndsWith(FileFormats[0]))
            {
                PictureBox picture = new()
                {
                    Name = "picture",
                    Size = new(45, 45),
                    Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName),
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                };
                picture.Click += Pic_Click;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture);
                GC.Collect();
```

`PictureBox picture = new()` is throwing the exception.

```
  readonly HttpClient httpClient = new();
    public static readonly string FolderPath = @".\Storage";

    public void Detailed_View_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshData();
    }



    private void Pic_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            PicGen _ = new(pictureBox);
        }
    }

    private void Gif_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PictureBox pictureBox)
        {
            string url = pictureBox.Name;
            GifGen _ = new(url);
        }

    }

    private async void RefreshData()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory = new(FolderPath);
        FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
        string[] FileFormats = { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".txt" };
        for (int pictureCreator = 0; pictureCreator < files.Length; pictureCreator++)
        {
            FileInfo file = files[pictureCreator];
            if (file.FullName.EndsWith(FileFormats[3]))
            {
                string url = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
                if (url != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Image gif = Image.FromStream(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url));
                        PictureBox picture = new()
                        {
                            Name = url,
                            Size = new(45, 45),
                            Image = gif,
                            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                        };
                        picture.Click += Gif_Click;
                        flowLayoutPanelGif.Controls.Add(picture);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (file.FullName.EndsWith(FileFormats[0]))
            {
                PictureBox picture = new()
                {
                    Name = "picture",
                    Size = new(45, 45),
                    Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName),
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                };
                picture.Click += Pic_Click;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picture);

            }

        }

    }


    private void BTN_AddGif_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string picID = new String(TXT_Add.Text.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            string picURL = TXT_Add.Text;
            string picLocation = FolderPath + "\\" + picID + ".txt";
            File.WriteAllText(picLocation, picURL);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
            flowLayoutPanelGif.Controls.Clear();
            RefreshData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
}
```

}

Context: When the form loads, I want to display every image and in their own flowlayoutpanels. However, when the user enters a url of a gif in the textbox, I clear each flaylayoutpanel to avoid duplicating each image and gif and instead include the new one among the already loaded images and gifs.
However, when the number of images exceed four, there's a big chance that the line `PictureBox picture = new()` throw's an out of memory exception. I have not had this exception appear when the number of images was just four.
The biggest image size is 78kb, but as pointed out by the comments, I multiplied the height, width and bit depth (Bit Depth = 32 * Width = 293 * Height = 254) and the result is 2381504 however I'm not sure what unit that's in.

Comment: "80kb" is likely the compressed size. You need to compute the actual unpacked size, i.e. width * height * bytes per pixel. Also note that an image might require more than one buffer due to double buffering etc. And if you really want to know where the memory goes you should use a memory profiler, that will give you your answer much faster than just looking at the code.

Comment: OutOfMemory does not necessarily mean what you think it means. System just could not get the resource connected to memory or memory is fragmented and a segment of the needed size could not be retrieved. The concrete problem may be surfaced by a 
profiler. Be aware that every control here needs a handle (on a kernel object) that are not infinite. 55 Pictureboxes does not sound like much but if you got disposing/recreating wrong here handles might exhaust fast.

Comment: What is the relation between the two snippets you have posted? Try to post a complete sample of your code, without cutting pieces. Also specify when / how is this code called -- If you're using `[Control].Controls.Clear()` to remove the PictureBoxes, then don't, you need to dispose of those Controls and the images you have added to actually *remove* them -- What is the size of the largest image you're trying to load? -- Remove all `GC.Collect()` stuff, it's irrelevant here

Comment: Hey, sorry for the bad formatting. The second snippet is directly under the first one in my code. The largest image I'm trying to load is 78kb. I added `GC.Collect()` as an attempt to fix the issue. Thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: Well, post the complete code, including the method that contains it and give context (as mentioned, how / when this code is called) -- The size in KB of the file is not the size of Image, that's its Width and Height -- There's nothing to collect when you load images -- If something can be collected, it will be collected anyway, when actually needed (assuming disposable object that hold unmanaged resources are correctly disposed)

Comment: I've edited the post to include the stuff you mentioned, sorry about the delay if I misunderstood

Comment: These: `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();` and `flowLayoutPanelGif.Controls.Clear();` are the main problem (read my previous comment). The other is here: `Image gif = Image.FromStream(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url));` (not checking that the Stream represents a valid image or whether the method succeeded) -- I don't understand this code: `if (sender is PictureBox pictureBox) { PicGen _ = new(pictureBox); }`